# Facebook API - Multiple actions - 1 API Request

Tags: php, jquery, facebook

so i searched here and there yet i couldn't find anything except the outdated FQL that's gonna get limited or removed ( not quite sure ). So i'm building a app and i want to make it to post in let's say all the friends's walls but i don't wanna use a for loop because that will eat the host's CPU like a mad dog. My question is can you  suggest a method ?

What I currently got:

- Long lived tokens
- JQuery + PHP login

Comment: Again: https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/#february-2013

Answer (score 1):

Let's clarify a couple of things here:

1. [Facebook Query Language (FQL)](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/fql/) is **not** outdated and as far as I know, there are no plans to deprecate it!
2. Posting to friends wall *is* going to be **removed** in [February 2013](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/#february-2013)
3. Facebook always recommends using user-initiated sharing models instead of automating the process.

Answer (score 0):

read about the Batch Requests concept here: 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/

this will enable you to make multiple graph API calls at once

but, this is extremely not recommended to make 1000 calls with it, and it probably won't work at all because you will easily reach facebook's call timeout.
FQL will be a better method in this case because you can do it in one query (with start and limits)

Comment: _“FQL will be a better method”_ – no it won’t, because you can not “create” anything (post to friend’s walls was the asker’s topic) using FQL, but only query existing data.

Comment: sorry, missed the part when he wants to spam his friends - anyway, Facebook will soon remove the ability to post on your friends wall, so the question isn't so relevant